# Why do those two ways to set a variable to all 1s lead to different results?

Tags: c

I recently discovered a discrepancy between two ways to set a variable to all 1s in C.
Here is a small code sample to illustrate the odd behaviour on my 64 bit Linux system.

```
// compile with `gcc -o weird_shift_behaviour weird_shift_behaviour.c`

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    long long foo = 0;
    long long bar = 0;
    int i;
    puts("<foo> will be set to all 1s by repeatedly shifting 1 to the left and OR-ing the result with <foo>.");
    puts("<bar> will be set to all 1s by repeatedly OR-ing it with 1 and shifting <bar> to the left one step.");
    for(i=0;i<8*(int)sizeof(long long)-1;++i){
        foo |= (1<<i);
        bar = bar<<1 | 1;
        printf("<i>: %02d <foo>: %016llx <bar>: %016llx \n",i,foo,bar);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I do know that this is not the canonical way to set an integer type to all 1s in C, but I did try it nonetheless. Here is the interesting part of the output the sample program generates:

```
<i>: 29 <foo>: 000000003fffffff <bar>: 000000003fffffff 
<i>: 30 <foo>: 000000007fffffff <bar>: 000000007fffffff 
<i>: 31 <foo>: ffffffffffffffff <bar>: 00000000ffffffff 
<i>: 32 <foo>: ffffffffffffffff <bar>: 00000001ffffffff
```

Why does this odd behaviour occur? I could not think of any reasonable explanation so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1<<i
```

`1` is of type `int` and `1 << 31` is undefined behavior when `int` is 32-bit wide.

From the C Standard:

> (C99, 6.5.7p4) "The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. [...] If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 x 2 ^ E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

To fix your issue, change `1<<i` with `1ULL << i`.

Comment: @coffeeholic : No `int` can be max 4 byte wide. On 64-bit system `long` is 8-byte wide. Check it using `sizeof`.

Comment: @coffeeholic `int` is at least 16-bit wide and is very likely to be 32-bit wide in a 64-bit system (except in some exotic Cray system where it is 64-bit).

Comment: w00t, you're right, int is just 4 bytes wide even on a 64 bit system.
Looks like I'm not the brightest bulb in the barrel.

Comment: No, it's up to the implementation, but `int` is indeed 4 bytes on Visual Studio compiling for x64.

Comment: I am sorry for my obvious, blatant and inexcusable lack of a deeper understanding of C that lead to this question.

Comment: Basically `1 << 31` is negative (as a 4-byte int), which causes the upper 32-bits to be ones when it's promoted to 64-bit for ORing.